# regex : limit overall match length to 5 characters

Tags: regex, maxlength

I would like to limit the matches to matches that are at least 5 characters long.
The regular expression selects words that are combination of letters and numbers:

```
[A-Za-z0-9-]*([a-zA-Z-]+[0-9-]+|[0-9-]+[a-zA-Z-]+)
```

So for instance on text *'3D and also P315 or P35600 and 077333C-0320-PO-3633-001-PME033  3 times 45 is 4D45'* it gives 5 matches:

match1: *3D*,

match2: *P315*,

match3: *P356000*,

match4: *077333C-0320-PO-3633-001-PME033*

match5: *4D45*.

I have tried this expression so that the matches are *P356000* and *077333C-0320-PO-3633-001-PME033* only because they are matches longer than 5 characters:

```
([A-Za-z0-9]*([a-zA-Z-]+[0-9]+|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z-]+)){5,}
```

but it does not work.

Any idea how to do that?

And how to simply withdraw the matches from the original sentence?

Comment: Just filter the array returned from match with the criteria that each entry needs to have a length of >= 5.

Comment: Which language/framework/application are you using? If the target regex engine supports lookahead assertions you can prefix the expression with `(?=.{5,})`

Comment: I propose [`(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*\D)[\w-]{5,}`](https://regex101.com/r/50BA56/1)

Comment: This is just great ! Thank you all. Your solution Hao is very elegant !